# Delete a User with foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm working on a Laravel Application for managing case studies with a full admin dashboard that includes CRUD functionality for user accounts that can log into the system.

In short, a case study and a user have a one to many relationship (a user can have many case studies, a case study can only be authored by one user); a case study must always have a user that authored it. The problem I'm  encountering is when I call the destroy method on my users controller to delete a user, it does not work because there are case studies in the DB that have that user associated with them and I run into a foreign key constraint violation.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to solve this problem. I was thinking I could create a user called "Deleted User" to assign case studies to when their author is deleted. This "Deleted User" could never be deleted or modified in the DB. You would also not be able to log into the system as "Deleted User".

I don't know if this would be considered a bad practice and I also think I may have an issue with scalability. For example, if a user has 5,000 case studies associated with them and that user is deleted, I suspect it would take a very long time to alter 5,000 rows in the DB to attach the "Deleted User" user.

I'm using Sentinel to manage different levels of user permissions as well, so when a user is deleted, I also detach that user from it's respective role in the role_users pivot table.

I don't know if it's at all helpful, but here's my destroy function on UsersController:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->delete();

    $role = Sentinel::findById($id)->roles()->first();
    $role->users()->detach($id);

    Helpers::flash('The user has been successfully deleted.');
    return redirect(route('admin.users.index'));
}
```

Here's my migrations:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->text('permissions')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_login')->nullable();
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->unique('email');
    });


    Schema::create('studies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 150);
        $table->string('problem');
        $table->string('solution');
        $table->string('analysis');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->boolean('draft');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        // Foreign key constraints
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On your sentinel's migration file there should be `user_id` which one is foreign key of `users` table.

I assume at the bottom of your all columns you have created the foreign key constraint. Just chain it with `->onDelete('cascade')`. It will delete all case studies associated with a user if the user is deleted.

Your foreign key code should look like this:

```
 Schema::table('sentinels', function ($table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
      $table->.....
      $table->.....

      $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('set null');
 )};
```

> Perform this before database migration. If already migrated run `php artisan migrate:rollback` on command line.
>   Edit your migration file and again migrate your database running this code in command prompt `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i know that would work if I was trying to delete the case study as well but the idea is that a user is deleted however any case studies associated with that user remain the DB.

Comment: thanks again for taking the time to help me out. Maybe i'm not being totally clear with what i'm trying to accomplish. I'd like for a user to be deleted and NOT have it cascade and delete all of that user's associated case studies. Since a foreign key cannot be NULL, a case study must always have a user associated with it. I've edited my initial post to include my migrations, that might help clear things up.

Comment: For future readers don't forget to set to `->nullable();`had some weird issues without it